# Marketing Cloud - Remove View Email as Web Page from Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template

I'm creating emails in MC using Content Builder, and am noticing that the "View Email as Web Page" link is getting automatically added to the emails I want to send out. Is there a way to prevent this from occurring? Is there a way to control where I want this text to be displayed in an email, and whether I want it to be displayed at all?

Comment: Are you using custom templates or salesforce marketing cloud inbuilt email templates for this scenario?

Comment: Hi @BradSapkota, thanks for the response, I'm using the built in email templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"View Email as Web Page" is automatically added to all the emails when you use "System Default" Headers, you can create a custom header or check option none in the Administration (Headers and Footers) section.